# How do i get each expected string from a multiple string line

Tags: php, string

I dont really no how to start my steatment to output my expected result but in my achievement i have a hug string characters line example

```
 $string = 'newboy1fineboy8badboy12 boy4andothers...';
```

my problem is how do i get all the boy and related characters from the string line example: 
my expected result should be boy1boy8boy12boy4

Big thanks for time and impact in my solution

Comment: Use regex `boy\d+`

Comment: @u_mulder
am sorry i dont no how to go with that  (regex) is that a server function? Or can you kindly give a soluction using it in full answer to my problem?

Comment: You can use preg_match_all() to get all data in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all and then foreach to display all data as per your requirement like below:

```
<?PHP
$string = 'newboy1fineboy8badboy12 boy4andothers...';
$string = preg_match_all('/boy\d+/', $string, $results);

foreach($results[0] as $val){
    echo $val;
    echo "<br>";
}

// Output
boy8
boy12
boy4

?>
```

Or if you want to get all your required data in 1 string then like below:

```
foreach($results[0] as $val){
    $updated_string .= $val;
    $updated_string .= "&nbsp;";
}
echo $updated_string;
// Output
boy8 boy12 boy4
```

If you want to get data like runboy8 runboy12 runboy4 then you have to use str_replace like below to further update your string:

```
$updated_string = str_replace("boy","runboy",$string);
// Output will be runboy8 runboy12 runboy4
```

Comment: Gugta
with your method how do i replace it output with a diffrent string example runboy8 runboy12 runboy4

Comment: Yes you can do it with str_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all()` to do that:

```
<?php
$string = 'newboy1fineboy8badboy12 boy4andothers...';

preg_match_all('/boy\d+/', $string, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Then you can access the list of matching strings as `$results[0]`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => boy1
            [1] => boy8
            [2] => boy12
            [3] => boy4
        )
)
```