# How do detect an expected incorrect string in a string line

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I have a large string  example

**newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollows...**

my problem is how do i detect an incorrect boy from each of the string line output example my expected output should be like:
**boay1 boiy12** 
this my tried code:

```
$string = "newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollows...";
$string = preg_match_all("/bo\d+/", $string, $results);
foreach($results[0] as $val){
    if($val !== boy) {
        echo $val;
    }
```

but i get no output in return.
Big thanks for your time and impact in my soluction

Comment: _but i no output in return_. The output is syntax error in this case.

Comment: I was saying but i get no output in returns please see my new ediction

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your question. What is exactly an *incorrect boy*? How many wrong/missing letters are allowed and where? Only one more letter before the `y`?

Comment: Not doing much of this coding yourself are you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740916/how-do-i-get-each-expected-string-from-a-multiple-string-line

Comment: @casimir et hippolyte

let me start by saying as  in a string line of 
$string = "newboy1fineboy8badboy12 boy4andothers";

    $string = preg_match_all("/bo\d+/", $string, $results);
    foreach($results[0] as $val){
echo $val;
    }
my output is boy1 boy8 boy12 boy4 so how do i get the !preg_match (boy) when the    $string = "newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollows...";
belive you get my question clear now

Comment: Perhaps, you want [`'~bo\pL{2,}\d+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/BHaO0o/1) if you need to match substrings that start with `bo`, then have 2 or more letters and then 1+ digits.

Comment: Am confuse on your idea can you give a code ediction of your idea in answer?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/X454ZH, is it what you need?

Comment: Please explain: do you need to check if there is `bo`, then any letters, then `y`, then again 0+ letters and then digits? Perhaps, you need [`'~bo(?:\pL+y|y\pL+)\d+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/BHaO0o/2)? See https://ideone.com/lwfov8. I can provide an answer once I know what you need.

Comment: Yes thanks alot but i want to be able to get this result using [ IF ] steatement just as it is steated in my question

Comment: Like https://ideone.com/khMDLI?

Comment: Wow you very wonderfull useing your current method i hope i can get both output for correct and incurrect boy in the string example correct boy8 boy4
incorrect boay1 boiy12 in string line of newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix you code as follows:

```
$string = "newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollows...";
$string = preg_match_all("/(bo\pL+)\d+/", $string, $results,  PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach($results as $val){
    if($val[1] !== "boy") {
        echo $val[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/khMDLI).

The point is to match `bo`, then any 1+ letters and *capture* that part, and then just match 1+ digits. See the regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHaO0o/3)):

```
'~(bo\pL+)\d+~'
```

**Details**

- `(bo\pL+)` -  Group 1: `bo` and 1+ letters
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Inside the `foreach`, `$val[1]` contains the value captured into Group 1, and if it is not equal to `boy`, you may get the whole match accessing `$val[0]` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks alot but how i do get the correct expected string also example correct boy8 boy4
incorrect expect string boay1 boiy12
trying with 
$string = "newboay1fineboy8badboiy12 boy4andothersfollow.";
$string = preg_match_all("/(bo\pL+)\d+/", $string, $results,  PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach($results as $val){
    if($val[1] !== "boy") {
        echo "$val[0] incorrect ";
    }
echo "implode($val) correct";
}
but it output both correct and incorrect expected string